# Pass Values from Textboxes / Radio buttons to One TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, textbox

I have few different radio buttons and four textboxes.

What I want to achieve is to get values from all textboxes and display it all in one summary textbox (summary).

I have managed to get values from all radio button however I cannot get the values from textboxes.

I want this to look like this:

> RB1 - RB2 -RB3 - TXTB1 - TXTB2 - TXTB3 - TXTB4

Radio button as well as textboxes are all in groupboxes.

```
private void summary_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var radios = this.Controls.OfType<GroupBox>().OrderBy(x => x.TabIndex)
       .SelectMany(x => x.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>())
       .Where(x => x.Checked == true)
       .Select(x => x.Text).ToList();

    this.summary.Text = string.Join("-", radios);

    var textboxes = this.Controls.OfType<GroupBox>().OrderBy(x => x.TabIndex)
        .SelectMany(x => x.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
        .Select(x => x.Text).ToList();

    this.summary.Text = string.Join("-", textboxes);
}
```

Comment: It is not clear from your question what is the problem. You don't get the TextBoxes text? The summary is empty?

Comment: Are you sure they are of Type TexBox? Not some other type, e.g. from Telerik?

Comment: And what's quite strange is that you put this code in `summary_TextChanged()` when the only change is presumably made inside the event handler.

Comment: Code works fine here. Did you perhaps forget to type some TEXT into the textboxes ... ?

Comment: @ Steve, when I enter text into textboxes, the summary textbox does not get updated with it. When I select radio button, the text from radio buttons goes automatically to summary textbox.

Comment: @ Peter B, I have added this.summary.AppendText("-" + string.Join("-", textboxes));  it now gets all values from textboxes however an app freezes

Comment: The code above seems to be called when something in the textbox _summary_ changes. But inside the code you change the same textbox and this creates an infinite loop. You have attached this code to the summary textbox?

Comment: Yes, it is attached to summary textbox. Should I change **summary_TextChanged()** to something else?

Answer (score 1):

The last line replaces the content of the summary textbox with the content of the textboxes, thus the content of the radiobuttons is lost.
What you need to do is to Append to the previous content

```
 // Adding also a - to separate radiobuttons from textboxes
 this.summary.AppendText("-" + string.Join("-", textboxes));
```

Also if you have attached this code to the `summary` TextChanged event then there is a big problem because when this code is called you change the content of the same TextBox `summary` and thus the code recalls itself.

Usually, the WinForms engine is smart enough to avoid this kind of recursion but your code defeats the safety measures of the Form engine because you change the `summary` content two times.

So what is probably happening is this:

1. summary is blank, you trigger in some way the TextChanged event
2. summary is set to the radios text, TextChanged event is recalled
   again
3. summary is set to the same radio text, nothing changes and
   the WinForms engine avoid to recall the TextChanged event handler
4. summary is set to the textboxes text (or new text is appended to the previous), TextChanged is recalled
5. continue from point 2

Do not add this code as the event handler for the summary textbox, just use it as the event handler for the other textboxes TextChanged event or for the RadioButtons checked event.

Comment: Thank you, it seems ok when I added this code to group box where in which all textboxes are placed, however the radio buttons don't work well now. I will review the code once again and get back to you.

Comment: It is of the utmost importance the choice where do you add this code. I would set every textbox.TextChanged event to this code, and I would do the same thing to the RadioButton.CheckedChanged event

Comment: Should I add the entire code (radios + textboxes) to each radiobutton and textbox?

Comment: You go to the Form designer, choose the Properties window (for each textbox and radiobutton) switch to the event page (click on the lightning icon ) choose the TextChanged event (or CheckedChanged for radios) and set it to the code once called _summary_TextChanged_ (be sure to have the same parameters passed object and eventargs)